# How to get the fields from object_list in django template

Tags: django, templates, generics

I am using this as Generci view

```
book_info = {
    "queryset" : Book.objects.all(),
    "template_name" : "book/book_lists.html",
}
```

Now in my template book_lists i have

```
 {% for book in object_list %}
            <tr>
            <td>{{ book.name }}</td>
```

Is there any way i can loop through all like we have in form

```
{% for field in form %}
forn.label_tag and field
```

so that i can use it for all Models

so basically i want something like

```
{% for obj in object_list %}
                <tr>
                {% for fields in obj %}
                 <td> {{field.name}}:{{field}} </td>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a get_fields function in your model(s) which you can then use in the templates to access the fields and values generically. Here is a complete example.

books/models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Book(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        author = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        isbn = models.IntegerField(max_length=20)
        published = models.BooleanField()

        def get_fields_and_values(self):
            return [(field, field.value_to_string(self)) for field in Book._meta.fields]
```

templates/books/book_list.html:

```
<table>
 {% for obj in object_list %}
    <tr>
        {% for fld, val in obj.get_fields_and_values %}
            <td>{{ fld.name }} : {{ val }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
 {% endfor %}
</table>
```